# group and combine items using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

```
public class Product
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Amount { get; set; }
}

public List<Product> Products = new List<Product>()
{
    new Product() { Code="A1", Name="Vacuum", Amount = "10" },
    new Product() { Code="A2", Name="Iron", Amount = "20" },
    new Product() { Code="A3", Name="Kettle", Amount = "13" },
    new Product() { Code="A2", Name="Microwave", Amount = "11" },
    new Product() { Code="A3", Name="Dryer", Amount = "3" }
};
```

I need to select all products without duplicate code. Products with the same code should be combined into one line, in this case name and amount should be separated by commas. How to modify the following code to make it more elegant

```
    var list1 = new List<Product>();
    var gl = Products.GroupBy(x => x.Code).Where(x => x.Count() > 1);
    gl.ToList().ForEach(x => list1.AddRange(x));

    var list2 = Products.Where(x => !list1.Contains(x)).ToList(); // uniq values

    var list3 = gl.Select(x =>
    {
        var p = new Product() { Code = x.Key };
        p.Name = string.Join(",", x.ToList().Select(r => r.Name).Distinct());
        p.Amount = string.Join(",", x.ToList().Select(r => r.Amount).Distinct());
        return p;
    }).ToList();

    list2.AddRange(list3);
    list2.ForEach(x =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{x.Code.PadRight(20)},{x.Name.PadRight(20)},{x.Amount.PadRight(20)}");
    });
```

the result should be:

```
Code  Name              Amount
A1    Vacuum            10
A2    Iron, Microwave   20, 11
A3    Kettle, Dryer     13, 3
```

Comment: This is a good question apart from the fact there is no expected output, and the part that describes it, is a little ambiguous

Comment: @TheGeneral edited , i put the expected result

Comment: @John my logic is to separate duplicate and unique codes into different list , then process duplicates , then add them back into list of products with unique code

Comment: Why though? Why not just use a single `.GroupBy(...).Select(...)`? After all, a single item will become a group with a single item, and then will come out the other side as a single item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `GroupBy` on `Code`, then iterate over it to get the individual elements to combine using `string.Join()`.

```
var results = products
    .GroupBy
    ( 
        p => p.Code
    )
    .Select
    (
        g => new 
        {
            Code = g.Key, 
            Name = string.Join
            (
                ",",
                g.Select( p => p.Name )
            ), 
            Amount = string.Join
            (
                ",", 
                g.Select( p => p.Amount.ToString() )
            )
        }
    );
```

Output:

```
A1 Vacuum 10
A2 Iron,Microwave 20,11
A3 Kettle,Dryer 13,3
```

[Link to working example on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bItbVE)